# Fire a method from a Static Cell in a Table view Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

In my code i have a table with static cell inside storyboards. I'm trying to fire a method upon clicking the last static cell.

What should i write in the code to make this happen. How can i refer static cells inside the code without firing error.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In the viewController add:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *theStaticCell;
```

Connect that outlet to the cell in the storyboard.

Now in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
UITableViewCell *theCellClicked = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (theCellClicked == theStaticCell) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I had to change `self.table` to `self.tableView`.

Comment: but is it optimized ? if it is not a static cell it will create a new cell ?

Comment: maybe the use of indexPathForCell is best

Comment: @CiNN Just for posterity, this will not create a new cell.

Answer (score 9):

With static cells, you can still implement `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and check the indexPath. One approach, is that you define the particular indexPath with `#define`, and check to see whether the seleted row is at that indexPath, and if yes, call `[self myMethod].`

Comment: i tried that, when call indexPath.row it throws a error back at me during runtime. How can i check the 3rd section 2nd row?

Comment: if ([indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2]])   [self myMethod];

Comment: I like @MaxGabriel's answer better because you can reorder the cells without changing your code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take when mixing static and dynamic cells,

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                    if let staticIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(self.staticCell) where staticIndexPath == indexPath {
// ADD CODE HERE 
                }
        }
```

this avoids creating a new cell.
We all are used to create the cell and configure it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1):

Following CiNN answer, this is the **Swift 3** version that solves the issue.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let staticIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: OUTLET_TO_YOUR_CELL), staticIndexPath == indexPath {
        // ADD CODE HERE
    }
}
```

this approach allow to not necessary implement cellForRow method, specially if you are using static cells on storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were having the same problem I was. I kept getting an error when overriding `tableView:didSelectRowAt`, and the reason was that I'm used to just calling `super.tableView:didSelectRowAt`, but in this case we don't want to do that. So just **remove the call to the super class method** to avoid the run-time error.